# D3 stacked cylinder chart to full height

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, d3.js

As per the title, I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to create a stacked cylinder which scales proportionally to the height. Below is a illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: cylinder]

As you can see there three different sections - no matter what the figures are it should always fill proportionally to the height, in this case ~234px.

What would be the best way to achieve this? The dataset will be an array of objects.

TIA :)

Comment: Use the [stack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, d3 doesn't have good ways of rendering objects in 3d -- I'd look at three.js to do it with webgl if you're looking to do a lot of 3d graphs.

But, you don't even need d3. Making a cylinder turns out to be fairly simple with matrix3d css transforms (see http://jsfiddle.net/L2dsr0v0/1/), and after that all you will need is a little bit of js to make multiple cylinders and make scaling work.

```
transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.52, -0.85, 0, 0, 0.85, 0.52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

If you want to review linear algebra for your transforms, http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/ is a good place to start.